# jQuery insert.after for multiple items

Tags: jquery

I am using this small script to re-order a div:

```
    <script>
    jQuery("#comp").insertAfter("#comparer");
    });
    </script>
```

However I have this item multiple times and the code just seems to work for the first one and neglect / skip all others. Is there a way to have this applied to all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Id should be unique. `#` selector will return only one element.
- If you have multiple elements with same id, then change the id to
  class.
- You can use `.` for the class selector.
- Use `.clone()` to create a copy of the element. Other wise it will reposition the original element.
- Always wrap your code inside dom ready.

Then your code will look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".comp").insertAfter(".comparer");
});
```

Comment: If you have several `.comp`s and `.comparer`s, and you want each `comp` to follow a specific `comparer`, this would probably fail. The solution would be to have something to uniquely identify each pair, then have each one find its fellow. With this answer, every `.comparer` would probably be followed by ALL `.comp`s.